# Sending Textfield input on ButtonClick or Enter Key

Tags: java, listview, button, javafx, textinput

I'm trying to make a Chat, so that when I press enter or press the 'Send' Button, the input of the Textfield will go into a ListView. And it does it's job, although the code is really messy.

My controller code is as following:

```
public void initialize() {
        sendButton.setDisable(true);

}

public void isChatEmpty() {
    boolean isChatEmpty = textInput.getText().isEmpty();
    sendButton.setDisable(isChatEmpty);
}
public void sendMessageOnClick(){
    sendButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
        String message = textInput.getText();
        chatHistory.getItems().add("Sorin: " + message + "\n");
        textInput.setText(null);
        sendButton.setDisable(true);
    });
}
public void sendMessageOnEnter(){
    textInput.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            String message = textInput.getText();
            chatHistory.getItems().add("Sorin: " + message + "\n");
            textInput.setText(null);
            sendButton.setDisable(true);
            System.out.print("test");
        }
    });
}
```

I know it works because I can see it in the GUI, but I somehow, get a Nullpointer on my 'isChatEmpty', which to be fair, I do not know why.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.Controller.isChatEmpty(Controller.java:29)
```

Also, is there a way to combine the two Lambdas functions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of enter and click there is an easy way to deal with this: Use the `onAction` method for both. For `TextField` this is triggered when you press enter. Furthermore those handlers should be assigned from fxml. Also use binding to disable the button:

```xml
<TextField fx:id="textInput" onAction="#send"/>
<Button fx:id="sendButton" text="Send" onAction="#send"/>
```

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    sendButton.disableProperty().bind(textInput.textProperty().isEmpty());
}

@FXML
private void send() {
    String message = textInput.getText();
    if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
        chatHistory.getItems().add("Sorin: " + message);
        textInput.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `isChatEmpty()` method the result of `textInput.getText()` is `null` as you set it with `textInput.setText(null);`. 
This `null` causes NPE (see docs for `String.isEmpty()`).

To resolve this you can remove `isChatEmpty()` method and setup unidirectional binding:

```
public void initialize() {
    sendButton.disableProperty().bind(textInput.textProperty().isEmpty());
}
```

Note the `.isEmpty()` here is not a call to `String.isEmpty()` but to
`StringExpression.isEmpty()` what generates binding of type `BooleanBinding`.

Comment: That's nicely put! I've now replaced the initialization method, and also deleted isChatEmpty(), but I get this `Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` 

May you also look at my second question?

Comment: I've somehow fixed it, by just not using `textInput.setText(null)`, but just by   using `textInput.clear()` which, surprisingly, made it work :)