# Convert euros to another currency after choosing said currency, putting the amount (in euros), and the result using the comma for decimal

Tags: javafx

I'm working on a code where the user chooses a currency and the program will convert the amount, in euros, to the chosen currency. The only 2 issues I'm having are that, firstly, I want the calculation to happen after the user hits enter, and secondly, I want the result to have the following format "1234,56", in other words, instead of using the typical period to separate decimal, I want it to be a comma.

Here's what I've done so far. (This works, but it's missing the 2 things mentioned above)

PS: the conversion rates were already given to me, I didn't choose them.

```
private void onAction(ActionEvent event) {
        do{
            try{
                double conversor = 0;
                String euros = ValorEuros.getText();
                double cantEuros = 
                        Double.parseDouble(euros.replace(',','.'));
                if(!ValorEuros.getText().equals("") && 
                        (Libra.isSelected() || Dolar_americano.isSelected() 
                        || Rupia_india.isSelected() || 
                        Yuan_chino.isSelected())){
                    if(Libra.isSelected()){
                        conversor = cantEuros * 0.88;
                    }
                    else if(Dolar_americano.isSelected()){
                        conversor = cantEuros * 1.19;
                    }
                    else if(Rupia_india.isSelected()){
                        conversor = cantEuros * 80.22;
                    }
                    else{
                        conversor = cantEuros * 7.5;
                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String redondeado = df.format(conversor);
                ResultadoConversion.setText(redondeado);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){ResultadoConversion.setText("Error en formato de número");}
        }while(isSelected(event));
    }

    @FXML
    private boolean isSelected(ActionEvent event) {
        return event.isConsumed();
    }

    @FXML
    private boolean onKeyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        return event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER;
    }
```

Comment: Why not `NumberFormat::getCurrencyInstance` whith the desired `Locale`?

Comment: See also [_Sending Textfield input on ButtonClick or Enter Key_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49806739/230513).

Answer (score 4):

## Perform Action on Enter

I assume your input is a `TextField`. If that is the case, then all you need to do is set the field's `onAction` handler.

```java
someTextField.setOnAction(e -> {
    // do something...
});
```

On all platforms, this handler will be invoked when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the text field has focus.

---

## Formatting

You can use [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) to customize which character to use for certain parts of the format. For example, the following:

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ROOT);
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');

    var formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00", symbols);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(1234.56));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(5.3));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(117));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(0.42));
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
1234,56
5,30
117,00
0,42
```

If all you want is to do is set `,` for the decimal separator and use that relatively simple pattern, then the above should work just fine. But this approach is not very user friendly, unless you know every expected user will be okay with seeing `,` as the decimal separator for monetary values. Ideally, you should be taking the user's locale into account and/or, if the effort to implement is worth it, allow the user to choose a locale in the application.

### Currency

When formatting currency you should generally format it in the user's locale, regardless of the type of currency being formatted. And it would probably be a good idea to include the currency's localized symbol in the output. Both these things will help prevent confusion on the part of the user.

You could implement this via `DecimalFormat` directly with an appropriate pattern, but there is no reason to reinvent the wheel. Use [`NumberFormat#getCurrencyInstance(Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)) to get a currency formatter for a given locale. Once you have the formatter you can then set the appropriate [`Currency`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html) on it. For example:

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var currency = Currency.getInstance("USD");
    test(currency, Locale.US);
    test(currency, Locale.FRANCE);
  }

  static void test(Currency currency, Locale locale) {
    var formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    formatter.setCurrency(currency);
    System.out.printf(
        "[Currency = %s, Locale = %s]: %s%n", currency, locale, formatter.format(1234.56));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[Currency = USD, Locale = en_US]: $1,234.56
[Currency = USD, Locale = fr_FR]: 1 234,56 $US
```

Note how the same currency is formatted differently between the two locales.